# Rails - undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass in Sessions#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I'm trying to login I'm getting:

```
undefined method `admin' for nil:NilClass
```

which is called from the `layouts/_head.html.erb` partial

_head.html.erb:

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
  <% if @current_user.admin %>
    <%= button_to 'Swap to user', to_user_path(User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).id), method: :put,
                    class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= button_to 'Swap to admin', to_admin_path(User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]).id), method: :put,
                    class: 'btn btn-warning' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see, `session[:user_id]` exists. Here is application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_user
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def set_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find_by(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

Also the login button works through Ajax. So why am I getting `@current_user` as `nil`, if it's defines `before_action` in the  application controller? (Remember: `session[:user_id] != nil`)

Comment: i'd say no user with user_id exists. try find_by! - it will raise an error if the user has not been found, instead of just returning nil

Comment: `session[:user_id]` exists dose not mean the `@current_user` is not nil

Comment: @srecnig session_dump: user_id: 5,find_by! not helped

Comment: so a user with id 5 exists?

Comment: @srecnig yes,non of a user wasnt deleted

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `find_by` is incorrect. It should be:

```
@current_user = User.find_by(:id => session[:user_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solve is to define @current_user in create method,like

```
def create
user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
  respond_to do |format|
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
       session[:user_id] = user.id
       @current_user = user
       format.js { }
    else
       format.js {flash.now[:notice] = 'Wrong pass/name'}
    end
  end
end
```

guesss its not absolute right,but one of possible method